# Control Codes within Strings

Tags: string, eclipse, shell, controls

What would be the purpose for the use of control code `\b` and `\a` in a string?
Why does the programmer not simply delete a value, instead of adding a `\b` control code... and at the same time insert `\a` for alerts. `\a` does not produce the intended result in the interactive shell in `Canopy` or `Eclipse`.
What would be some examples where these control codes prove to be useful?

Lastly, from the textbook I am reading, `'\a` does not produce the desired result in the `IDLE` interactive shell, but works properly in command shell.'

I understand the difference between script and interactive shell, however, I do not understand what is meant by the command shell? Is the book referencing the Command Terminal (`MacOS`)?

Comment: print('Hello World\b') would print Hello Worl. In what instance is \b useful? In addition, print(1\a2\a3\a4\a5\a) is supposed to produce 5 beeps (heard from speakers), however, the textbook says that the beeps will not be heard if ran from script or interactive shell, only in the command shell. I do not know what a command shell is...

Comment: Python, using Canopy IDLE